# XTB API JSON cannot modify existing trade position

Tags: json, xapi

I am using a xAPI Playground for testing, link here:
https://playground.xapi.pro/
I want to edit/modify existing position with command: `tradeTransaction`.
Documentation says to modify existing position I should use "type" as 3 and "cmd" should match existing position (0 for BUY and 1 for SELL)

```
{
    "command": "tradeTransaction",
    "arguments": {
        "tradeTransInfo": {
            "cmd": 1,
            "customComment": "Some text",
            "expiration": 0,
            "order": order_number_as_int ,
            "price": open_price_as_double,
            "sl": my_double_value,
            "tp": my_another_double_value,
            "symbol": "f.e. OIL.WTI",
            "type": 3,
            "volume": 0.01
        }
    }
}
```

Error code

```
{
    "status": false,
    "errorCode": "SE199",
    "errorDescr": "Internal error"
}
```

All possible data collected from API about existing position:

> {'cmd': 1, 'order': 474325736, 'digits': 2, 'offset': 0, 'order2': 474325838, 'position': 474325736, 'symbol': 'OIL.WTI', 'comment': '', 'customComment': '', 'commission': 0.0, 'storage': 0.0, 'margin_rate': 0.0, 'close_price': 76.65, 'open_price': 76.57, 'nominalValue': 0.0, 'profit': -3.56, 'volume': 0.01, 'sl': 80.0, 'tp': 70.0, 'closed': False, 'timestamp': 1676665564666, 'spread': 0, 'taxes': 0.0, 'open_time': 1676663063081, 'open_timeString': 'Fri Feb 17 20:44:23 CET 2023', 'close_time': None, 'close_timeString': None, 'expiration': None, 'expirationString': None},

API documentation is here:
http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#tradeTransaction

Of course I tried every possible value in "cmd" and "type" but it does not help.
Error code sometimes are different, for example:

```json
{
    "command": "tradeTransaction",
    "arguments": {
        "tradeTransInfo": {
            "cmd": 3,
            "customComment": "Some text",
            "expiration": 0,
            "order": 474325838,
            "price": 0,
            "sl": 0,
            "tp": 0,
            "symbol": "OIL.WTI",
            "type": 3,
            "volume": 0.01
        }
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "errorCode": "BE4",
    "errorDescr": "remaining nominal must be greater than zero"
}
```

Any ideas what I can do wrong?
I am in touch with XTB support, still waiting for response.

Comment: SOLVED: Simply use on "cmd" and "type" 0.
Order and symbol must be filled correctly.
XTB support does not see any issue, they tried with "cmd" and "type" 3 and for them it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use on "cmd" and "type" 0.

Order, open price and symbol must be filled correctly.

XTB support does not see any issue, they tried with "cmd" and "type" 3 and for them it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use getTrades to see your **position** ID
It's different from your **order** ID but has the same number of digits.

Use position ID instead of order ID in your command.

**EDIT :**
It's a bit more complicated but here's the point :

*XTB App* gives you Order ID and Position ID.
You **must** use Position ID to close the order.

And for the API :

*tradeTransaction* response gives you the 'order' field - you **can't** use this one to close order

**BUT**

*getTrades* gives you 3 fields :
'order', 'order2' and 'position'.

'order' seems to be the same as 'position' - which you **can** use to close you order

'order2' seems to be the same as *tradeTransaction*'s 'order' - once again you **can't** use this one.

Comment: No, this JSON requires order ID, not a position ID.
I have solved it, check comment on the top of the thread.